# Access global variable from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to initialize a Angular model with a JSON object which is embedded in a HTML page. Example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var tags = [{"name": "some json"}];
    </script>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `tags` field cannot be resolved, because it is looked up in the `$scope`. I tried to access the `tags` field in my controller like this:

```
function TagList($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.tags = $rootScope.tags;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

It works only if I include the `TagList` directly into the HTML page and render the JSON directly into this function.

How can I access the `tags` field in a separate js file in a Angular controller?

Answer (score 11):

There are at least two ways:

1. Declare your `tags` array in a standalone script tags, in which case your `tags` variable will be bound to window object. Inject $window into your controller to access your window-bound variables.
2. Declare your `tags` array inside the `ng-init` directive.

Showing both solutions:

HTML:

```
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var tags = [{"name": "some json"}];
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    tags: {{tags | json}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>  

  <div>
    <ul ng-init="tags = [{name: 'some json'}]">
      <li ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('AppController',
  [
    '$scope',
    '$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.tags = $window.tags;
    }
  ]
);
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6055Y4TApbC8DgdYR4QS?p=preview)

I strongly advise against polluting window object.

Comment: Is there any other way to initialise a variable in the view without having to declare it inside a HTML tag? For example, if the `tags` array declared inside `ng-init` above was a really large array and I want to initialise it in the view (from server side code for ex.) can I use something like `{{ tags = [{...}] }}` instead?

Comment: @Stewie there are also issues with the second approach. If the tags are generated through a jsonify method, and if they contain quotes, everything will brake

Comment: I can't see any better way than using $window for @GFoley83's use case; I have the same problem, I send down an initial JSON payload with the markup that I want to inject into the controller, but this is surprisingly difficult to do with Angular.  I don't like polluting the window object either (or having to pull in globals either), but it seems like the best way.

Comment: @ElYobo Yeah it is surprisingly difficult, with no clean way of solving it yet. I'm thinking I'd prefer to use something like `<input type="hidden" data-ng-init="tags = [{name: 'some json'}]" />` instead of having to pass around global variables.